# Machine readable zone missing from Vietnam visa. Is this going to be a problem?

Tags: visas, vietnam

I just received my Vietnam visa today, I'm leaving on the 5th of December. I noticed that my visa was missing some information (in the big white space) while I was referencing a similar image online.

I'm now told the big white space is called the MRZ.

[image: visa picture]

Is this going to cause any problems?

I'm in Chicago and had to receive the visa by mail from New York. I doubt I'd be able to get a replacement before I depart on Tuesday.

My last trip I did the visa on arrival, and the visa I received looked different than this one. I just want to make sure I'm good to go before I begin my trip.

Is not having my passport information in the MRZ going to cause any problems?

EDIT:

I have contacted the Consulate in New York with this email:

*Hello,
I received my Visa on Saturday. 
I noticed that none of my passport information was included in the big white space at the bottom of the visa (which I believe is called the MRZ).
I attached a picture of what I'm talking about.
Is this going to cause any problems not having my information there?
Thanks,
OP*

**And I received this in reply**

*It's consulat of vietnam visa. Thanks*

Not sure how to take that reply. But it seems like it won't matter.

To be safe, who can I contact further to reassure that this won't be a problem?

Comment: The passport number is not the blacked-out number to the right of the "holding passport of country/territory: USA"? With the heading "no."?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I was just about to edit my post title. Yes it is there. I misunderstood what goes in the white space. On some images online the white space is filled with the information on the bottom of the passport information page. So for me it looks like P<USALASTNAME<<FIRSTNAME<<MIDDLE<<<<<<etc...

Comment: @23k that is MRZ - Machine Readable Zone is used most for faster recognition of your visa data. I have not still found any restrictions here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport  about whether it may cause problems having no MRZ or not.

Comment: @pure_true any suggestions on who would be the best to call? Like I said nothing is open until Monday and I'm leaving on Tuesday...

Comment: @23k in that case I would call to Embassy of USA in Vietnam. One day I called to South Korea my country’s embassy and they gave me information I need. Can’t be sure about your case. Good luck

Comment: how did you go with this? we got ours and they are the same - worried they are fake!!!

Comment: @user78627 You will be fine if you received them from an embassy.

Comment: I don't think any ports in Vietnam have the machine to read those. Even all the passports are scanned manually. And machine-readable passport was not available yet for Vietnamese, which is a pain

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My girlfriend got in contact with her brother in Vietnam, who has a close friend that works at Tan Son Nhat International Airport. Long story short, this will not be a problem entering the country.

Ultimately it seems like it's up to each consulate to put information in the MRZ field or not.

**UPDATE:**

After entering Vietnam successfully, I can officially say that it's up to each specific consulate to decide to use the MRZ or not. It did not cause any problems when entering the country.

Comment: So, empty MRZ for Vietnam Visa - is it pretty usual thing ?

Comment: @pure_true It seems common enough. He sent additional reference pictures with a blank MRZ. However, I'll make sure to update my answer if I do run into any issues.